# The doubly exponential formula of quadratic recursion equations

Tags: sequences-and-series

As we all know that quadratic recursion equation $${x_{n + 1}} = a{x_n}^2 + b{x_n} + c$$ can be solved only if $$\Delta=(b - 1)^2 - 4ac=1\ \mathbb{or}\ 9$$

But in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/wiki/Index_to_OEIS:_Section_Aa#AHSL) I found some different results.

All quadratic recursion can be represented as $\displaystyle a_n=\left\lfloor c^{2^n}\right\rfloor$,

where $\mathbb{c}$ depends on the recursion equation, and different initial value has different $\mathbb{c}$ value.

eg:

$$\begin{align}
&a_{n+1}={a_n}^2+1,a_1=1 &\Rightarrow c=1.502 836\\
&a_{n + 1} = {a_n}^2 - 3a_n + 3, a_1 = 1 &\Rightarrow c = 1.526 526\\
&a_{n+1}＝a_n^2＋2,a_1＝1 &\Rightarrow c = 1.824 911\\
&a_{n+1}＝a_n^2＋2,a_1＝3 &\Rightarrow c = 3.330 300\\
\end{align}$$

---

*It doesn't like a formula, it seems more like a kind of encoding.*

What's the essence of this method?